# Checking for valid overloading

Tags: java, oop, overloading

I want to know whether this is a valid overloading :

```
public class OverLoadingTest{

     private void callFunction(Object object){
              System.out.println("Printing Object");
     }

     private void callFunction(String string){
              System.out.println("Printing String");
     }

}
```

Further more, since someone asked me this question.
If I do like this,

```
OverLoadingTest test = new OverLoadingTest();
test.callFunction(null);
```

what will be printed ?

Of course my opinion is that it isn't valid overloading at all.
So no question of the second part.

Please tell me about this with some explanation.

Comment: @FastSnail - Nope. It will call method with *String* argument

Comment: yes i was wrong .i forgot smallest possibility

Answer (score 3):

The method *with the least generic argument* is called. So, in your case, it will be method accepting  `String`

Note : If 2 classes are at the same level, then you will get an *ambiguous call* exception. For example if one method took `String` and another took `Exception`.

Comment: could you please explain the last line `if one method took String and another took Exception`

Comment: @Shail016 - See, If 2 classes are at *different* level in the *class hierarchy*, then the *lower* level class will be chosen. So, if the arguments were `IOException` and `Exception`, `IOException` will be printed since it is a *subclass* of `Exception` (the *least generic*). The same concept applies to `String` and `Object`. Since `String` is a *subclass* of `Object`. Now, if you have `IOException` and `InterruptedException`, then the call will be *ambiguous* since both classes are at the *same level*. Got it?

Comment: Also, the classes *must* have a relation between them. `FileNotFoundException` and `String` will give *compile-time* error

Answer (score 2):

```
If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method 
invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for 
the run-time method dispatch.
The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
```

See more details in [JSL 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

- In your case, String method will be invoked, if argument is `String` or `null` and for other argument's types `Object` method will be invoked.
- In your example, if you define one more method with argument type that is not `String` (e.g Integer), can't compile the source as it is ambiguous to be invoked between the methods with `String` and `Integer` as they are same level.